# Running HTTP and Websocket listeners on the same port returns error 500 without message

Tags: http, websocket, ballerina

I'm doing a project where I need to migrate a service that listens to http requests as well to requests on a websocket on the same port. From the websocket package documentation [ballerina/websocket](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/websocket/latest#Listener) it mentions that the websocket listener can be initialized with another listener.

However, when doing it with an http listener, the moment an handshake is sent to the websocket service it is returned an error 500 without a message. I tried with the example on the Ballerina by example page and that was the result as well. Here is the code that I used.

```
import ballerina/io;
import ballerina/websocket;
import ballerina/http;

listener http:Listener httpListener = new http:Listener(9090);
listener websocket:Listener wsListener = new websocket:Listener(httpListener);

service /chat on wsListener {

    resource function get .() returns websocket:Service {
        // Accept the WebSocket upgrade by returning a `websocket:Service`.
        return new ChatService();
    }
}

service class ChatService {
    *websocket:Service;

    // This `remote function` is triggered when a new message is received
    // from a client. It accepts `anydata` as the function argument. The received data 
    // will be converted to the data type stated as the function argument.
    remote function onMessage(websocket:Caller caller, string chatMessage) returns error? {
        io:println(chatMessage);
        check caller->writeMessage("Hello!, How are you?");
    }
}
```

As such, I want to know if it is possible to have an http and websocket service on the same port in Ballerina? And if so, what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be because the `ballerina/websocket` uses HTTP version 1.1 and the `ballerina/http` uses HTTP version 2 by default. Can you check by changing the HTTP version to 1.1 in the HTTP listener?

Just added the HTTP version configuration in your code:

```
import ballerina/io;
import ballerina/websocket;
import ballerina/http;

listener http:Listener httpListener = new http:Listener(9090, {
    httpVersion: http:HTTP_1_1
});
listener websocket:Listener wsListener = new websocket:Listener(httpListener);

service /chat on wsListener {

    resource function get .() returns websocket:Service {
        // Accept the WebSocket upgrade by returning a `websocket:Service`.
        return new ChatService();
    }
}

service class ChatService {
    *websocket:Service;

    // This `remote function` is triggered when a new message is received
    // from a client. It accepts `anydata` as the function argument. The received data 
    // will be converted to the data type stated as the function argument.
    remote function onMessage(websocket:Caller caller, string chatMessage) returns error? {
        io:println(chatMessage);
        check caller->writeMessage("Hello!, How are you?");
    }
}
```

Comment: It works!! Thaks a lot for your help!!